# How to copy Ethereum Blockchain from one node to another

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

I have installed the Ethereum Mist client on a 6 GB RAM Ubuntu 14.04 machine and it is working as expected. I tried installing another node on a second 3GB RAM Ubuntu 14.04 machine and on this node, the block synchronisation process is not terminating. Have tried number of times but each time the sync process stops somewhere around 400,000+ blocks ( when the full chain is around 1,000,000+ long) but there is no error. It is just that the network activity stops, nothing gets downloaded and process just sits there ... until I kill it. Two Questions

1. Is the sync process stalling because of the lower RAM? Or is there any other process that I need to figure out?
2. Is it possible for me to copy the block chain from my active Ethereum node and simply place it in the correct directory? If so, then which directories should I copy or what should I do. I dont have the GETH console and hence cannot issue the admin.copychain command

Answer (score 1):

Check if `~/.config/Mist` contains several GB of data, then the blockchain would be here.
If not, check the size of `~/.ethereum/`

The [README](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/blob/b425a3b1c811910ede5f1fec23368049db615ce1/README.md#installation) states that the data folder is `~/.config/Mist` but not sure if it includes the Blockchain.

Once the right folder is found, copying it to the other machine should work. If you mind copying also other data than the blockchain(especially if you copy `~/.config/Mist`), you have to be more selective about which folder(s) to copy.